# Inset Face flickering

Tags: faces

I'm creating a roof for a church model, where there's a small "hole" on the rectangular figure, but when I try to inset face, it's start to flickering and creating vertices and edges where shouldn't be.

I'm trying deleting extra edges, extra vertices, extra faces, but nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens to me when there are overlapping faces, in my experience.
Try deleting *Only Faces* of surrounding topology and then re-creating the faces with the appropriate vertices

Comment: Thanks I did it!